# Xming and picture rendering in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rendering, figure, xming

I'm using xming 6.9.0.31 on Windows XP computer to connect to Linux server and run Matlab scripts there. I have 2 configurations of xming and both have problems related to matlab output figures.

In one configuration everything works on the first script run, all figures come fine. But on the second run (of the same script) xming crashes when it outputs some figures. It might work longer if i create figures in command line, but eventually it will crash anyway, on the process of outputting new figure.

In another configuration (borrowed from andLinux installation) xming doesn't crash and is able to output figures, but only simple plots, if there is something more complicated, with a lot of data, just figure frame appears with whatever was under the figure window. The same thing happens if i actually run andLinux and connect to Matlab from there.

Seems that this is somehow related to memory. Are there any options for xming which are related to used memory? As far as i understand it'a only showing the image which was created on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is related to OpenGl setting another renderer might help.

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','Zbuffer')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I still don't understand the reason for this problem (i mean the server is the same, Matlab is the same, and in one case it works one time but crashes next time, in other case doesn't plot at all with OpenGl renderer). Is it somehow related to Xming settings?

Comment: Great! Accepting answers (clicking checkmark) is considered as good style ;-). It must be a X Window client/server issue caused by opengl. Haven't tracked it down so far.